# Can I force a unit test to fail if there are no Asserts?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

Some programmers in my team sometimes write unit tests which call the method, gets the result but forget to call the proper `Assert` methods to actually check what's happening.

I was wondering if there is any configuration I can do to force MSTest to fail the test if no verification is done. I remember seeing something like this in DUnit, but could not find it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Perhaps write a unit test that scans all the unit test methods and looks for Assert code?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ But there could be an error when writing those tests, so you also need to test the tests that test the tests.

Comment: Joking aside, I think oɔɯǝɹ has about the best solution possible.

Comment: I don't know if that's a good idea, not all unit tests actually have an Assert. Some unit tests test for an exception.

Comment: @BobHorn: those tests should be tagged with `[ExpectedException(...)]` then?

Comment: If you CAN get this to work, expect to see a bunch of Assert.IsTrue(true); in your codebase

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Right, so you could test for that as well. But aquinas has a great point. I don't think there's a foolproof way to do this. Use code reviews.

Comment: Nice! `Assert.IsTrue(true)` should be easier to check :)

Comment: We use code reviews, I wanted just a tool to catch this errors before code review. You know, code reviews requires humans to see this, and humans suck.

Comment: agreed, code reviews (and agreement on usage of assert) would be the right way to prevent this from happening. people before tools! hoewever, this could be an extra automated failsafe. especially when the build breaks on it :-)

Comment: @Doug If you start checking `Assert.IsTrue(true)` then expect to see `bool randomlyNamedBool = true; Assert.IsTrue(randomlyNamedBool)`... you're going to dig yourself into a big ditch if you try to catch these kinds of things.

Comment: You tagged tdd, if you are using tdd you're not going to face this kind of mistakes cause a first unit test should fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Test-Lint from Roy Osherove](http://www.typemock.com/test-lint/) and co. It's static code analysis for test code.

I tried it out once when it was out for public alpha/beta..  was pretty well-behaved. However didn't try out this specific need. I don't think MSTest or most unit testing frameworks will guard against this out-of-the-box.

Also aquinas has a valid comment.. Education might work better than inspection-and-the-stick. You may even be able to create a custom rule to catch rogue asserts.. Check the tool out.

From the home page of the tool,

> What issues does it detect?
>   Currently Test Lint finds a set of common problems:
>   * Missing asserts in your tests

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of such a feature. Unit testing without Asserts is simply testing that no errors are thrown in which case would typically pass every time.

I am rather surprised that your programmers are actually writing tests without Asserts, this seems very unprofessional. I would suggest pointing them towards reading a few online courses on Test Driven Development where typically you write a test to fail and then make the programming changes to make it pass (where in this case Assert.IsTrue(true) wouldn't even begin to make sense.

Also provide the template:

```
[Test]
public void TestCase
{
    //Setup
    //Run Test
    //Process Results
    //Assert
}
```

I would highly suggest making the purchase for this screencast: 
http://tekpub.com/productions/ft_tdd_wilson

It provides a good idea on how to write unit tests and how to properly follow TDD.

Comment: It's a side effect of metrics-driven orgs. e.g. if you enforce a rule that the build will fail and the check-in rejected if the test coverage drops by 1 %, you'll see lots of similar 'process-gaming'.

Comment: Using a TDD approach however, the test coverage should never drop. And also 'cheating the system' should result in the programmers getting a severe warning. It is a horrendous approach to programming.

Comment: Usually it shouldn't. However out there in enterprise coding, strange things have been known to happen. It's a side-effect of 'fake/inadequate buy-in' from the developers towards TDD. Professionalism is sometimes not as abundant as we'd like it to be.